# Will locking one USA credit bureau be detrimental?

Tags: credit-score

TransUnion has failed to remove an incorrect report of collection long after Experian and EquiFax have verified it incorrect and **removed** it.  AFAIK, this is a violation of Federal law.  They are not even reporting it as disputed in spite of several phone calls.  They are also failing to report changes that the creditor claims to have sent and which the other two agencies have already updated.

That's background.  Because of this, I have considered advising the "victim" (a relative denied credit due to this nonexistent collection) to lock TransUnion against inquiries.  But before I go out on that limb, if he has a good score from the other two, but Trans cannot be queried, will that work against him?

Comment: What do you mean by "lock TransUnion against inquiries"? You can't stop a bank from "querying" a particular credit bureau.

Comment: Yes, I can.  I am no longer able to get credit cards or even increase the limit on the one I have because I locked my record on all three bureaus.  Anyone trying to inquire, with or without my permission, gets no information.

Comment: Trying to selectively present your credit profiles to the creditors isn't going to work if they are already wanting to pull from all three, meaning they are well aware of the potential discrepancies. If anything it makes them more suspicious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Placing a credit freeze will not affect your credit score. However, based on the comments, there is more to this. You cannot decide which credit bureau the bank will contact to request a copy of your credit report/score. As you have already mentioned, you were given a code to unlock your account when you apply for new lines of credit.

Certain banks only request reports from certain credit bureaus. Therefore, if you apply for a line of credit at Bank X and if they only pull credit from TransUnion and you refuse to "unlock" your account, then Bank X may not approve for the loan because they don't have access to your credit report/score.

In addition, since you did place a freeze on your account, you have to contact the credit bureau directly to lift the freeze if you are applying for new credit. When you are deciding to apply for new credit, you should inform the bank that you have a credit freeze and they will tell you which credit bureau to contact.

As I mentioned in one of my comments, the underlying issue is that TU is not removing error from your TU credit report, you should consider contacting a lawyer to resolve that. I hope that makes sense, and best of luck in getting this resolved!

https://www.consumer.ftc.gov/articles/0497-credit-freeze-faqs

Comment: I told him he should write a letter pointing out that they are violating federal law and CC: attorney general.  My experience is that little note on the bottom of a little gets them scrambling to resolve it before the A.G. calls them.  But he's a little impatient to get a card that has certain travel benefits.  I'm not interested in unlocking my own account because I haven't needed credit in five years.  I locked them when someone tried to access my Social Security online.

Comment: So, perhaps he's better off finding out which bureau they check.  Apparently one of the places he went checked all three and turned him down based on the error.

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to ask and some banks do check all three and some check one. My bank for my auto loan checked only Experian. Never hurts to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You can't effectively.

If someone applies for credit (loans, etc), he signs that a credit check is authorized (or he doesn't get credit). This signature overrides the locking; if not the creditor will ask him to remove the locking (or give no credit).

Comment: My signature does NOT override the lock.  For them to get any results, I have to login and enter the ten-digit code to unlock.  But my question is not what happens when they can't do a check.  It's what happens when they can do a check on two, but TransUnion tells them it is locked.

Comment: Nothing happens. They tell you it's locked and then they ask you that you verify it's you applying. The bank could decline you the loan if you refuse to verify its actually you applying.

Comment: I am not asking about identity checks.  I am asking about credit checks.  They know my identity usually by passport or other such.  But they can't get my FICO unless I can remember and enter the code.  That's MY scenario.  I asked what is likely to happen if Equifax and Experian tell them my relative has a good score and Transunion says "locked" or no info, or whatever it is they say.

Comment: @WGroleau That's what the freeze is for - people who've had their identity stolen. I can't type a comprehensive answer here (I'm on my phone.). I think your underlying problem is that TU is not reporting the correct information (according to you). I think you should consult a lawyer to get that fixed.

Comment: If you cannot open the locking (or decline to do so), you are exactly behaving as an identity thief would. No bank will take the risk to give you a credit after that, even if you have a passport.